# can I find position in R while avoiding looping?

Tags: r

This is an "R" question:

suppose I have a vector of 3 letters for example: "BBSSHHSRBSBBS" what I like to find is the position of the first "S" that appears after "B" sequence. For example in the vector above the first "S" that appears after "B" sequences will appear in the 3-rd place the 10-th place and the last place(13)

I can do trivially using loops but I like to find out if there is any way to do it in "R" without looping at all.

The function should get an R vector as an input and return the vector of "S" positions as an output

Thanks,

Answer (score 7):

Another base R solution

```
str <- "BBSSHHSRBSBBS"
pos <- unlist(gregexpr("BS", str))
```

Note that `gregexpr` accepts regular expressions so you can catch much more complex patterns.

Comment: My mind didn't go there but I really like this solution.  Very flexible. +1

Comment: You need to add 1 to find the first S after a B.

Comment: This is good but what happens if I have a sequence of the form "BHHS" it will fail? because the return should be position 4?

Comment: If it doesn't find anything it will return -1. If you want to allow characters between B and S you can use an expression like "B(.)?S" (or something like that)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe with str_locate_all:

```
library(stringr)
v <- "BBSSHHSRBSBBS"
str_locate_all(v, "BS")
[[1]]
     start end
[1,]     2   3
[2,]     9  10
[3,]    12  13
```

Comment: You'll want to use a regex in there instead of just `"BS"` for the inevitable follow-up for the case where the first S after a B does not _immediately_ follow the B.

Answer (score 3):

in base R.

```
s <- "BBSSHHSRBSBBS"
sl <- strsplit(s, 'BS')[[1]]
pos <- nchar(sl[1]) + 2 # to get the S, 1 to get the B
```

Answer (score 2):

This version works also for input like "BHHS"

```
s1 <- "BBSSHHSRBSBBS"
s2 <- "BHHS"

spos <- function (s) {
  pat <- "B[^S]*(S)"
  m <- gregexpr(pat,s, perl=TRUE)
  as.vector(attr(m[[1]], "capture.start"))
}

spos(s1)
spos(s2)
```

Comment: feel free to accept this or any other answer here if your problem is solved :-)